# Colorbox cboxOverlay position IE

Tags: internet-explorer, position, colorbox

I have a problem with Colorbox .
When you click cboxOverlay position is at the bottom,,, But only in IE .

Loook link: [cboxOverlay position IE problem](http://paryzinska.pl/projekty.html)

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix your css.

```
#cboxOverlay {
    position: absolute !important;
}
```